# File extension 'js' not supported in exactarget

Tags: marketing-cloud

About 2 hours ago, I was unable to upload js files to the portfolio. What happen?

This morning I pushed a new build. I noticed a bug, fixed it, and now I am getting that error.

Answer (score 1):

Switching browsers fixes the problem.

Comment: Hey! how are you uploading the javascript? Getting the same error

Comment: I switched browsers. Simple as that. Let me know if that doesn't work.

Comment: Worked like a charm !

Comment: Think it would help to make your answer clearer I.e which browser worked and which didn't